# How do I sync categories in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2016

I've been googling but can't find a sensible and easy solution..

I'm giving categories a chance, but between using my 3 computers, I'm not planning on managing my catagories on all 3 of them seperatly.

I'm using Outlook 2016.

Is there like a file I could sync through dropbox/onedrive/whatever and get my categories synced?

Comment: What type of Outlook account do you use (Exchange/Office365, IMAP, POP3, ...)?

Comment: The account in outlook seems to be labeled as "Exchange active sync". Like this: https://i.imgur.com/6Ri7r92.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your're using the Microsoft's Outlook.com service (outlook.be). First of all, you need to remove it and then add again. This will swtich the account type from using EAS (outdated and deprecated) to Exchange. After that you'll get all your categories automatically synced between all devices connected to this account.